# LDAP commands using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, terminal, ldap

I am trying to automate a few LDAP commands by running a jenkins job. I want to fire some LDAP commands which I usually fire from the terminal but instead of the terminal, I want to do it from jenkins so that I don't have to type in those commands everytime. Can anyone tell me how can I approach this?

Comment: Have you used Jenkins before? Actually, you just past the shell command and it executes it for you. So not sure where the actual problem is..

Comment: I did execute in the shell command  and it did not execute. It said command not found. Plus, I have to SSH into another environment to fire the LDAP commands and I do all this through terminal. So I'm not really sure if Shell is gonna accept the ldap commands

Comment: If no `ldapsearch` or whatever is installed on the Jenkins build agent then sure, it does not work. Either install it there or run from a Docker container containing necessary tools. SSHing into another system to run test commands.. well.. not sure if that fits so well to the nature of Jenkins.